# GCM client for Desktop

Tags: android, c++, google-cloud-messaging

Is there any way to login into a GCM server and receive messages from a Desktop Windows C++ application? I want to be able to login into my GCM server using some kind of C++ GCM client.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

> GCM Client
>
> SEE ALSO
>
> Getting Started GCM Server A GCM client is a GCM-enabled app that runs
>   on an Android device. To write your client code, we recommend that you
>   use the new GoogleCloudMessaging APIs. The client helper library that
>   was offered in previous versions of GCM still works, but it has been
>   superseded by the more efficient GoogleCloudMessaging APIs.
>
> A full GCM implementation requires both a client implementation and a
>   server-side implementation. For a step-by-step guide to creating a
>   complete sample implementation that includes both client and server,
>   see Getting Started.

I think it is designed for android device.
Probably you can hack and install a whole android somewhere but, buy is easier in this way:

Write an Android client as google expect to a cheap phone (20$) When you receive message send it over wifi to your desktop Apache server via HTTP POST, and problem solved, simple :)

Comment: Wow! that a such answer, thank you. The point is that I need a REAL and TRUSTED answer, not just a "I think...". I will try to investigate more

Comment: @DídacPérez than I will remove the "I think... " from sentence :) IDK why want to make a hack and waste 600 hours, instead of doing simple in 30 hours. Technically it is possible, I don't see why not, but isn't easy. Is like you want to use a Mercedes 600 SL for pow and harwesting. It is not designed that system for that task, but technically you can use it... but is simple to use other for that task